# sql submission shows different texts not what i actually submitted i'm trying to submit on DHIVEHI language

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

Hi guys please help me here i'm  to submit my posts on DHIVEHI language but sql database shows it something like this (???????&%$) what to do???? here is code some parts are written in DHIVEHI and class MVDIV is dhivehi language style class. plx help me guys?

FORM PAGE

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="post.php" method="post">
    <label class="mvdiv" for="type">ވައްތަރު </label>
    <input type="text" id="type" name="type" dir="rtl" class="thaanaKeyboardInput mvdiv form-control" >
  </div>
  <button name="submit"   type="submit data" value="data"  class="btn btn-default mvdiv">ފޮނުއްވާ</button>
</form>

POST.php page
if (isset($_POST["type"])) {
 $name = crypt($_POST["type"]);
 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO story_type (name) 
         VALUES('$name')") or die (mysql_error());
        echo "$name";
 }
```

Comment: this is a charset issue trey searching for mysql support for that language i don't have great knowledge over unicode 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode.html
start here

Comment: tried by changing unicode but dosen't work